# How to make UBUNTU SERVER a vpn server

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to setup a Native VPN on an ubuntu server OS. I dont want to use a thirdparty software like OpenVPN. I prefer to have a server which I can have hundreds of users connect remotely and have a secure internet browsing.

Is it possible?

Comment: OpenVPN is in the Ubuntu main repos. How much more native does it get?

Comment: Well, wireguard is also part of the main repos, and wireguard is far simpler to configure and better performing and I suspect less resource-demandin than openvpn. And from a security point of view the codebase of wireguard is in my opinion less prone to have security holes due to its small size and being a kernel module, has been subject to very thorough analysis by kernel developers. I would vote for wireguard on any day. I have also used OpenVPN and it works fine, but it has had its share of security vulnerabilities, and is a bit complicated to configure, as compared to wireguard.

Comment: Your ISP may have something to say about you trying to host a VPN with hundreds using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at wireguard.